# Auto Sliding Horizontal Slider that slide on click as well

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-transitions, css-animations, css-transforms

The Demo [Horizontal slider](https://jsfiddle.net/PHI_VIVEK/vo7sa1be/) slides on click by changing the attribute `checked="checked"`.

But I want the slider to Auto slide after an interval of 2000ms can be done using some javaScript/jQuery.

Below is the jQuery Code that I am using which ain't working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".slider li:first-child").attr("checked");
  setTimeout(autoSlide, 2000);
});

function autoSlide() {
  var next = $("input").attr("checked").next();
  if (next.length) {
    input.removeAttr("checked");
    input.attr("checked", checked);
  } else {
    $('.slider li:first-child').attr("checked");
    setTimeout(autoSlide, 1000);
  }
}
```

Kindly direct on getting the Horizontal slider - [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/PHI_VIVEK/vo7sa1be/) auto slide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $next=$(".slider input:first").next();

  setTimeout(autoSlide, 2000);

  function autoSlide(){
   $next.trigger('click');
   if ($next.is(':last-child')) $next=$("input:first");
   else $next=$next.next();
   setTimeout(autoSlide, 2000);
  }
});
```

From your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s5agwu9t/